# How do i get a batch script to show real time progress bar, while waiting for another script to finish?

Tags: batch-file

Hi im not really good in writing batch scripts, im new to this, i really need help,

The script i have needs to do an unattended installation, 
i got that part to work, what i need is to show a progress bar for the users to see the progress of the installation,

the script i have is below:

```
@echo off
echo --------------------------------------------------------------
echo --------------------------------------------------------------
echo Software is installing......
echo.
echo please wait, do not close!!
echo.
C:\files\gw18\win32\install.bat /unattended
cls
```

i found this really cool progress bar script, i need help to make it work with the above

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set Counter=0
set Schalter=2
set Width=0

:1
title Animation Box - Installation
set /a Counter=%Counter% + 1
set /a Display=%Counter% / 2
FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,%Display%) DO (
   set Display=!Display!²
)
cls
echo            Progress...                  %Counter%%%
echo     ²!Display:~2,47!
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
if "%Counter%" == "100" goto :1-End
goto :1
:1-End
echo.
echo Installation complete.
pause >nul
```

Or any progress bar code that will work 
Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

What I would recommend doing for the progress bar script, is make it so that the installer outputs a text file every time it completes a task. For example, when it completes `MOVE file.exe "C:\Program Files\Application"`, `echo EXE Move Completed. > 1.txt`.

Then, the progress bar script would constantly watch for those files, then update the progress bar accordingly. Example:

```
:watch1
if exist 1.txt goto update1
goto watch1

:update1
cls
echo Progress: 0==========            0
DEL 1.txt
goto watch2

:watch2
if exist 2.txt goto update2
goto watch2
```

And so on.

So every time the progress bar script finds a new file outputted by the installer, it adds a little bit more to the progress bar.

Hope this helped.